# CSC help - C# Get direct output

Tags: c#

when "csc" command is run from command line,it generates .exe file and then we have to run that .exe file to generate output.

what i need is that i want to get the output by providing the input file in a single line.

Ex:
**USUAL WAY**

> csc sample_add.cs

the above command generates sample_add.exe

> sample_add.exe 4 5

Output: The addition of 4 and 5 is 9

I want to write a single line in order to get the final output.

> "any command" sample_add.cs

Output: The addition of 4 and 5 is 9

Comment: that seems to be a ridiculous requirement.

Comment: What is "any command"?

Comment: "any Command" means any way to directly get the output by running in one single line.

Comment: @MitchWheat : ya..i'm running the code from another application which can accept only one line of command to generate output

Comment: So..."any command" is supposed to build an exe AND evaluate something?

Comment: yes. if only we are able to generate and execute in single line!!!

Answer (score 1):

Short of creating a batch file, there's really no way of getting csc.exe to do that. However, you might want to look into [ScriptCS](http://scriptcs.net).

Comment: what if i generate dll for my code.can we use it to get the things done?

Comment: its just not abt csc.exe .Can we do it using batch file?

Comment: What speaks against using a batch file?

Comment: I put an example batch file as answer (code formatting is practically impossible in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Doing the example given in the question within a batch file could look like that:

```
@echo off
rem %1 = CS source file
rem %2 = Number 1
rem %3 = Number 2

set SourceFile=%1
set ExeFile=%SourceFile:.cs=.exe%

csc %SourceFile%
if errorlevel 1 ...  <<<-- do error handling here.
                         Sorry, i don't know the exit codes of csc :(

if not errorlevel 1 %ExeFile% %2 %3
```